# Useful label for message box cancel/close button

Tags: buttons, labels, error-message, copywriting, messagebox

i'm reworking a message box that pops up when there was a specific error.

In the title and description it tells the user what went wrong. In the improved version i will include 2 buttons (in the current version there's only a close button captioned 'ok')

1 button which is the primary button links them to a contact form where they can get help from customer service. it is labeled 'contact. the 2nd button will close the box, and its labeled 'try later'.

My question is, does the 2nd button label make sense, giving it will close the box. would there be a better caption to this?

Comment: What made you decide that 'OK' was no longer the right caption to use? What is the action that the User was attempting that can yield the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the message box already explains the error, the Try later can be embedded within that message.

I'm not sure what all the possibilities of errors where you would need to use that message box are, but *"Okay", "Got it" or "Close"* will cover all use cases where you need to show a secondary action button after an error message description.

For instance, If you are doing maintenance that will take 6 hours on your website", This method will allow you replace the *Try again later* in the message itself to something like *"Try again by 12:00 GMT"*. These are cases where having that action text in the button may fail. And this is just one of many scenarios.

[image]